# can I close two collapsable panels in one click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 3 panels in my html file.
    The first panel contains table rows (always open). When I press on any table row, a new panel next to it opens (collapse) next to it to the right, lets call it the second panel.
    In the second panel, there is a button which when clicked a third panel opens (collapse) next to it to the right.
When the three panels are open and I press the table row in the first panel, only the second panel closes (collapse). 
    Is there a way to make the third panel closes too?

```
     <html> 
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.min.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
              
    <div class="row">
    <!-- First Panel -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">First Panel</div>
                   <div class="panel-body">
                       <table class="table table-striped">
                           <thead>
                               <tr>
                                   <th>Name</th>
                               </tr>
                           </thead>
                           <tbody>
                               <tr>
                                   <td><a data-toggle="collapse"                                                     href="#secondPanel">open second     panel</a>                                     </td>
                               </tr>
                           </tbody>
                       </table> 
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
              
            <!-- Second Panel -->
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default panel-collapse collapse"                         id="secondPanel">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Second Panel</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <table class="table table-striped">
                                <thead>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"                                    data-toggle="collapse"                                                            href="#thirdPanel">Reply</button>   
                                </tbody>
                            </table>     
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Third Panel -->
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default panel-collapse collapse"                         id="thirdPanel">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Third Panel</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <table class="table table-striped">
                                <thead>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <div class="well well-sm">some text</div>
                                </tbody>
                            </table> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You can do it via JavaScript: `$('.collapse').collapse()`

Comment: @DanEpp That's JQuery, not raw Javascript

Comment: @BenWainwright there is a "jquery" tag but you are right!

Comment: @AlonEitan I added my code , please help. Thank you :)

Comment: @fiscsp This is not angular. You don't have an angular module (`ngApp`), nor a controller and a view. If you want to use angular then you can start [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#collapse) with this collapse  example